# Oracle golden gate syncing oracle - mysql

Tags: mysql, oracle

Is it possible to sync data from oracle to mysql via golden gate like following.

```
Oracle Table
------------------------------------
Service
===========
service_id
service_name
service_code
op_id

Subscription
===========
sub_id
service_id


MYSQL table
------------------------------------
Subscription
=============
sub_id
service_id
service_name
op_id
```

So like above I need to sync data combining two tables in to on mysql table when doing the syncing. Don't have an idea whether this task can handle from Golden Gate as I never used it.

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite old but anyway...

I don't think it is possible. GoldenGate basically grabs REDO logs, extracts change data, then delivers it to the target database.
Amazon DMS may allow you to do it by using Schema Conversion Tool, though DMS does not support replication between on-premises DBs.